# What does "that" refer to in this context?

Tags: word-in-context, reference

Does "That" refer to "The abiding sense"?

> But don’t be fooled: enjoyment and happiness are not synonyms.
> Enjoyment is, at best, an answer to the rigors of routine; it is not
> the abiding sense of a life well lived. ***That comes*** with having lived
> life well at every level and to the very heart of its ultimate
> meaning.

Comment: **That** refers to "the abiding sense of a life well lived".

Comment: *"Happiness, (which can be seen as) the abiding sense of a life well lived, comes with ..."*